# Serializing a lucene query into JSON?

Tags: json, serialization, lucene

Is there a best practice for serializing Lucene queries into JSON format?  I saw elastic search query dsl, but it looks like it strays from lucene terminology.  Also, Lucene appears to be moving away from maintaining serialization code.

I am looking to have a "standard" format in JSON.  I need to be able to save a query, but when users are saving queries on the web UI, they are not entering `title:Matrix`.  We also have to be able to search the saved searches, then edit the saved searches.  It would be nice if there was a standard json format for representing a query.  Specifically a lucene query.

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: @rahul I have not. I think omu_negru gave a promising lead, but I never took the time to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

I know very little of Elasticsearch but I'm guessing they are doing this (also) because they support extra query functionality other than Lucene normally does.

If you just need to marshall/unmarshall the query, just treat it whole as a single unescaped string. If you want to break it down to key-value (field name/value) elements, don't forget you can have conjuction/disjunction/etc. So this is not trivial.

As for your comment on serialization code - don't think this applies to queries. `Query` has abstract `toString(String field)` method which each query subclass should implement and provide a parseable string. `toString()` just calls that - and this hasn't change for a long while, nor I see this changing as `Query` does not provide any other way of getting String representation so changing it would break a lot of code.

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Can you give an example?  I also updated my question, maybe that will help.

Comment: Lucene query has never been designed to be perfectly serializable into JSON. Your example `title:Matrix` can be, but there are more complex cases (conjunction, disjunction, parentheses, range queries) which are not trivial to map. I was suggesting you to store the query as a single string (e.g. '(+foo:bar -boo:baz) AND bob:[1 TO 2]') but if for some reason you need it to be broken into key-value pairs, you have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thats what I thought.  I think I'll need to do some research.

Answer (score 0):

Your standard query will have a tree-like structure, so i think translating that to Json should be trivial. Just create a recursive method that calls itself for boolean or dismax queries. The rest of the queries are (i think) terminal ones